# How can I keep the focus to my selected text when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, selection

I have a text selection for my editor in IE written in javascript.

```
checkedText = parent.frames['myframe'].document.selection.createRange();
```

Everything works ok just the first time. Then if I click a button the focus is gone for a while and the checkedText has the previous text as well. 
I tried also keep the focus with:

```
checkedText.select();
```

but it doesn't work. I know it is a but hard to explain my problem but if anyone has an idea I would appreciate it.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("test").select();
document.getElementById("test").focus();
```

Comment: But as you see the text is in a frame so I don't use any divs.

Comment: I did this                     parent.document.getElementById("myframe").select();
parent.document.getElementById("myframe").focus();
but it says error in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following not work? If not, maybe you can post a page showing the problem.

```
parent.frames['myframe'].focus();
checkedText.select();
```

Comment: Well it is difficult to post a page because it is too big. I will try yo explain it a bit better. 
I have a file text_creation.php and there I can choose my text. All the alerts here works fine which mean the text is selected right. Then I click a button and I get a color picker for paint my selected text. The function called is in a color.js file.
In the beginning of the file the text seems also right. When I pick a color (in a .click event) then immediately the text changes and keep the previous selection as well. I hope to be more clear now.

Thanks